# CSS Text Shake Only Inside DIV containing countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have countdown timer on my site.

The text inside the container of countdown timer is acting weird something like font-weight is on & off a bit.

This doesn't happen if position is not absolute or outside elements.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sakibanda/7qcrpq0x/1/

```
.last_sold {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: #000;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FC6;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: remove this  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1); from your .main-example .count.top class in css.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem

CSS:

```
.main-example .count.top{
    line-height: 3em  !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.

By the way here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qcrpq0x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Well I just wrapped your `.last_sold` inside one more `div` with some style and `position:absolute` and yea it works and hope this is what you want!!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7qcrpq0x/6/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="oneMore">
     <div class="last_sold">
          SHAKING INSIDE DIV
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.oneMore{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```